# How do I fix the syntax error for this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-tesseract

> File "C:\Users\Suhaas\Documents\ocr_local_image.py", line 8
>
> ```
> print pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.jpg'))
>                  ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: Have you tried commenting out this line? Python is known to report errors on line N mentioning line N+1.

Comment: python 3+ requires parentheses, while python 2 doesn't

Comment: I'm with @BarisDemiray on this.  Since it points to the `.` the it is probably a previous line (not necessarily N-1) missing a close bracket or some other delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it could be a missing parentheses based on examples from here: https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract

Try this:

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test.jpg')))
```

Comment: The OP has tagged `python-2.7`, which has the `print` *statement*.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Was just basing off of examples in the pytesseract docs.